# How to evict a specific cache line periodically?

Tags: gem5

I am trying to achieve periodical cache line evictions on the classic cache model (not Ruby). For example, in each 10us, L2 cache set 0 way 0 is evicted. I am not sure how this could be implemented.

Can someone give me some suggestions about this?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a cache event function that evicts the cache line then reschedules itself, though this would be by cycles so it would require coordinating that with the Python configuration.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the reply. I am not sure how python configurations can provide a clock-like signal. Could you please explain this further? I will appreciate it a lot.

Comment: It depends on the ```system.clk_domain.clock``` value in the python configuration. It defines the transition from clock cycles to seconds, so then with that knowledge you can have the event reschedule itself for whatever frequency of cycles you would like.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I will have a try.